# How to have catchall dynamic virtual maps in Postfix

Tags: postfix

How do I make `postfix` (or whatever), save separately incoming mail to `$anything@example.com` to `/var/emails/$anything`. Currently I have setup simple virtualmaps, but am kinda stuck there.

So,

- `test@example` => `/var/emails/test`
- `something@example.com` => `/var/emails/something`

and so on.

Currently I have mails `$anything@example.com` and it goes to a specific user "incoming". Just without separation.

Answer (score -1):

Just add an entry without the username portion of the email address.  For example:

```
test@example.com          /var/emails/test
something@example.com     /var/emails/something
@example.com              /var/emails/default
```

Any email sent to any address @example.com (other than test@example.com and something@example.com) will be delivered to the default mailbox file.

This is documented in the postfix man page for the virtual map (view with `man virtual`) under the section "TABLE SEARCH ORDER":

> The search order is as follows. The search stops upon the first successful lookup.
>
> - When the recipient has an optional address extension the user+extension@domain.tld address is looked up first.
>
>   With Postfix versions before 2.1, the optional address extension is always ignored.
> - The user@domain.tld address, without address extension, is looked up next.
> - Finally, the recipient @domain is looked up.

---

BTW, don't use `domain.com` or any other existing domain for an example, that domain belongs to someone else, and using it is about as rude as using a real person's name and address as an example.

Use either just the word "domain" (e.g. `user@domain`) or one of the example domains, e.g. `example.com`, `example.org`, `example.net`, or `example.edu`. These are reserved for use as examples and will never refer to a domain that is in use.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com for details.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm trying to have like a wildcard mapping, so I tried in virtualmaps `*@examle.com /var/mail/%1` but that also didn't work. :/

Comment: I've never tried it for virtual maps (but have for several other map types) but you should be able to use a pcre map instead of a hash map for virtual_alias_maps - see `man pcre_table`.

Comment: I just tried that, when running `postmap -n pcre:...` gives bulk mode error or something, and https://serverfault.com/questions/972173/unsupported-dictionary-type-pcre-postfix-header-checks trying here with `postmap pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual`, has no effect, the mail still gets delivered straight to user's mailbox. :/

Comment: that's not how you configure postfix to use a pcre map, that's how you tell postfix you've updated the map.  you need to edit `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and change the `virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` to `virtual_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual.pcre` (or whatever filename you choose for   the pcre map) and then edit the virtual.pcre file.  Like I said, I don't know for sure if virtual_maps works with pcre, but everything else in postfix can.

Comment: btw, as with most other maps in postfix, virtual_maps can have multiple map files - so you can have a hash: type AND a pcre: type map - e.g. `virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual, pcre:/etc/postfix/virtual.pcre`

Comment: So as I understand now, these map files CANNOT write to file, destination can only be another email or a local user account. Not achievable with postfix? Perhaps need maildir or something?

`Mar 31 10:48:46 ubuntu postfix/local[28475]: 26F4C13B46C: to=</var/mails/something@
mail.example.com>, orig_to=<something@example.com>, relay=local, de
lay=0.96, delays=0.72/0.01/0/0.23, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (unknown user: "/var/m
ails/something")`